# ORMLite. How to establish one-to-one relations of two tables related, like "primary key to foreign key"

Tags: java, postgresql, orm, ormlite

I have two tables, one of them have relations with another over foreign id to primary id.

And I have some model description, which in my opinion looks correct, but it doesn't work.

First table

```
public class Person {
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "person_id", foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    Patient patient;

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }
```

Second table

```
 public class Patient {
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "person_id", foreign = true)
    private Person personId;
```

When I try to find data from "Patient" over the "Person", I get a null pointer.
If change foreign key column name in person, I get PSQLException, because ResultSet does not contain such a column.

For debugging, I use simple main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Person p = new PersonDAO().getByUserId();
    System.out.println(p.getPatient());
}
```

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grw4k.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

> How to establish one-to-one relations of two tables related, like “primary key to foreign key”

The problem with the 1-to-1 relationship is that in the `Person` table there is a `patientId` field and in the `Patient` table there is a `personId` field.  But the ids only get set when they are created in the database.

This means that you will have to do 3 database operations:

- Create the `Person` in the database to get an ID associated with it by calling `personDao.create(...)`.
- Set the `Person` on the corresponding `Patient`, then create the `Patient` in the database with `patientDao.create(...)`.
- Set the `Patient` back on the `Person` entity now that the patient has has an id, then update it in the database with `personDao.update(...)`.

Couple of other things:

- I assume you are missing an argument to the `dao.getByUserId()` method in your post since it needs an id to find the particular one in question.
- I assume that `Patient` has an id field even though you don't show it in your post.
- The field in the `Patient` should be just `person`, not `personId`.  ORMLite will store an id in that field under the covers.  The field in `Person` is correctly called `patient`.

Hope this helps.